# Rally App SDK 2.0: Call to validate() by managed listener in rallymultiobjectpicker re-filters store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

I have been looking at the source code for the rallymultiobjectpicker, more specifically, this line, within the initEvents function:

```
this.mon(this.inputEl, 'keyup', this.validate, this);
```

which calls the validate function belonging to the object instance. However, upon further examination, I do not see any code the would trigger behavior to re-filter the store, such that external values are loaded/appended, which is what I am currently seeing.

Here is the source for the validate function (http://bit.ly/MXH6CB):

```
validate : function() {
    var me = this,
        isValid = me.isValid();
    if (isValid !== me.wasValid) {
        me.wasValid = isValid;
        me.fireEvent('validitychange', me, isValid);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Note: For what it's worth, remoteGroup, remoteSort, and remoteFilter are all set to false.

**EDIT**: Indeed, it is not the validate function that triggers the behavior, but the initFiltering function call to the AutoFilterable class that initializes a keypress listener, filtering on the text input.

```
_onStoreLoad: function() {
    this.removePlaceholderText();
    this.groupRecords();
    this.initFiltering();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The filtering is handled by the [AutoFilterable](https://rallytest1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.AutoFilterable) class, which is a private class within the SDK. The call to validate does not trigger the filtering.

Comment: Ok. I can see that now. It is the call to initFiltering in the _onStoreLoad function that initializes the listener to filter on text input. However, it seems that if this is called, the data is pulled from the original store? So, basically, if I set the store to one of my own derivation, input will cause the filtering to occur, returning the results from the original store which match that input pattern, which then repopulates the control. I suppose there is no simple workaround. I tried overriding _onStoreLoad to exclude the call, but then the displayField is not populated.